# How to import data from CSV file containing certain words?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file containing daily data on yields of different government bonds of varying maturities. The headers are formatted as by the country followed by the maturity of the bond, for eg UK 10Y. What I would like to do is just import all the yields for one government bond at all maturities for one date, so for example import all the UK government bond yields at a particular date. The first date is 07/01/2021.

I know I can use Pandas, but all the codes I have seen require to use usecols function when importing. I'd like to just create a function and import only the data that I want without using usecols.

[Snapshot of data, UK data is further right, but format is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmeNM.png)

Comment: So basically you want to import specific columns from one or several files, but you don't know from which file, based solely on the file name?

Comment: It's all in one file. I just want to create a function that imports the yields on all the maturities for one particular government bond. Perhaps a function which uses the header names, since all the names are formatted the same way:  country followed by maturity.

Comment: okay, and the date is a separate column in this file then?

Comment: The date is by row, and the bond yields by column

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import time
import datetime

col_to_check = "UK government bond yields"

get_after = "07/01/2021"

get_after = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(get_after, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())

with open("yourfile.csv", "r") as msg:
    data = msg.readlines()

index_to_check = data[0].split(",").index(col_to_check)

for i, v in enumerate(data):
    if i == 0: 
        pass
    else:
        date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(v.split(",")[index_to_check], "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
        if date > get_after:
            pass
        else:
            data[i] = ""

print ([x for x in data if x])
```

This is untested code as you did not provide a sample input but in principle it should work.

You have the header name of the column you want to check, the limit date.

You get the index of the first in your csv row. You convert the limit date to timestamp integer.

Then you read your data line by line and check. If the date/timestamp is greater than your limit you `pass`, else you assign empty value at the corresponding index of data.

Finally you remove empty elements to get the final list.

Comment: I've tried the code for 3M USD data, but it doesn't seem to work. Since the date in the CSV file is m/d/y, I changed the code from:  "%d/%m/%Y" to "%m/%d/%Y". I get an error saying 3M USD in not in list.